# getPage inside of deferred object printing?

Tags: python, asynchronous, twisted, addcallback

I'd like to create a callback that does a `getPage` on a specific url and prints that out when the operation is complete. Currently when I print `d` or `page` (see code below), I get a reference to the deferred object vs. the contents of `page`.

Why does the memory location of the deferred object change between print `page` and print `d`?

Eventually I'd like this program to cycle through a list of 4 of my websites, create callbacks for each of those individual connections, fire them off, and print each page as they are ready.  If it's not too much to ask, can this be demonstrated?

```
from twisted.web.client import getPage
from twisted.internet import reactor
from twisted.internet.defer import Deferred

def connect(url):
    page = getPage(url)
```

`print page` returns `<Deferred object at 0x23dcc68>`.

`print d` returns `<Deferred object at 0x7f1bacacc3b0>`.

Current result (using 'http://www.example.com' as an example):

```
d = Deferred()

d.addCallback(connect)

reactor.callWhenRunning(d.callback, 'http://www.example.com')

reactor.callLater(4, reactor.stop)

reactor.run()
```

Comment: I ended up creating a print function, adding getPage to a deferred, and attaching a callback to that deferred..  Figured it out, however wrong it may be, it works.  :D

Answer (score 0):

You should probably be using the newer, spiffier [`twisted.web.client.Agent`](http://twistedmatrix.com/documents/12.2.0/api/twisted.web.client.Agent.html) rather than the older and somewhat limited `getPage`.  Lucky for you there is [a very thorough tutorial on how to use `Agent`](http://twistedmatrix.com/documents/12.2.0/web/howto/client.html), as well as some of its companion classes like `ProxyAgent`, `RedirectAgent`, `CookieAgent`, and `ContentDecoderAgent`.

First, though, you may want to familiarize yourself with the documentation on [how to use `Deferred`s](http://twistedmatrix.com/documents/12.2.0/core/howto/defer.html).